# Evernote Integration - WSYIWYG Editor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, evernote

I'm attempting to integrate with Evernote, and while I have most of the setup complete, I can't seem to find a decent ENML WYSIWYG editor. Is this strictly a DIY thing at the moment, or is there an official plugin I can use to allow users to properly generate ENML? Am I stuck with having to convert HTML to ENML?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately yes, you'll have to do it by yourself...

This thread could be useful : http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/23658-enml-to-html-converter/

And this app : http://enml-editor.ping13.net/

Good luck